How to get Ubuntu to boot to uefi mode
I have an old MSI wind top that was running windows. I managed to install Ubuntu from a bootable usb through the windows recovery options. I'd like to change to mint and have made a bootable usb but cannot get Ubuntu to boot from the stick first. There doesn't appear to be an option to get to uefi either through Ubuntu or a key press on boot up. Stupidly, I didn't opt for a dual boot installation of Ubuntu. Any advice would be appreciated.

If you just want to use Ubuntu, and not Windows, go to UEFI settings and disable secure boot. Then, set USB drive to be the default boot option, and install Ubuntu

Mint is off topic on this site. But your question indicates that you are trying to install ubuntu

How the USB boots (UEFI vs legacy) is a matter of the UEFI settings and the way the USB was created -- the installed OS on the machine has nothing to do with that.  The supplied ISO has both boot capabilities, but the tool used to create the install media might have choices to allow only one sort of boot.

This question is similar to: No admin access to BIOS to change boot priority. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
